# Basic code optimization, exclusion of double grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to show only one row per column (PN) from result of calculations base on 2 indicators (WK) and (Prio), and I think that doing this in way below using double grouping is... stupid, but I see no other solution. Is there other way to reach same result as query below?

```sql
CREATE TABLE #table
(
    [PN] varchar(3) null
    ,[WK] int null
    ,[Prio] int null
);


INSERT INTO #table
(
    [PN]
    ,[WK]
    ,[Prio]
)

VALUES
    ('AAA',37,1)
    ,('AAA',37,2)
    ,('AAA',38,3)
    ,('BBB',39,1)
    ,('BBB',39,2)
    ,('BBB',37,3)
    ,('BBB',38,4)
    ,('CCC',null,1)
    ,('CCC',null,2)
    ,('CCC',37,3)
    ,('CCC',38,4);


SELECT GTG.[PN]
    ,GTG.[WK]
    ,MIN([Prio]) [Prio]

FROM
(
    SELECT [PN]
        ,MIN([WK]) [WK]

    FROM #table

    GROUP BY [PN]

) GTG

LEFT JOIN #table TMP
ON GTG.[PN] = TMP.[PN]
    and GTG.[WK] = TMP.[WK]

GROUP BY GTG.[PN],GTG.[WK];


DROP TABLE #table;
```

Comment: Please explain the calculation.  It is not obvious what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a Common Table Expression (CTE) with `ROW_NUMBER()`:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ad973/17)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    [PN] varchar(3) null
    ,[WK] int null
    ,[Prio] int null
);


INSERT INTO MyTable
(
    [PN]
    ,[WK]
    ,[Prio]
)

VALUES
    ('AAA',37,1)
    ,('AAA',37,2)
    ,('AAA',38,3)
    ,('BBB',39,1)
    ,('BBB',39,2)
    ,('BBB',37,3)
    ,('BBB',38,4)
    ,('CCC',null,1)
    ,('CCC',null,2)
    ,('CCC',37,3)
    ,('CCC',38,4);
```

**Query 1**:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
( SELECT [PN], 
         [WK], 
         [Prio], 
         ROW_Number() OVER (Partition BY [PN] ORDER BY COALESCE([WK], 999), [Prio]) AS RN
   FROM MyTable T1
 )
 SELECT [PN], [WK], [Prio]
 FROM CTE
 WHERE RN = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ad973/17/0)**:

```
|  PN | WK | Prio |
|-----|----|------|
| AAA | 37 |    1 |
| BBB | 37 |    3 |
| CCC | 37 |    3 |
```

Answer (score 0):

do you find below

```
SELECT GTG.[PN]
    ,min(GTG.[WK])
    ,MIN([Prio]) [Prio]    
FROM     

     #table GTG   

LEFT JOIN #table TMP
ON GTG.[PN] = TMP.[PN]
    and GTG.[WK] = TMP.[WK]

GROUP BY GTG.[PN]
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want window functions.  This should do what you want:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by pn order by coalesce(wk, 999), prio) as seqnum
      from #table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b826cc4bbea56204219acf4850a50186) is a db<>fiddle.

Note:  `wk` possibly represents a week value, so I replaced it with 999 when it is `NULL` for the sorting to be correct.  You could filter out `NULL` values or use a `CASE` expression if `COALESCE()` does not quite meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I think, we can use `Row_Number` window function to sort result first and then apply where clause. Please try this-

```
;with cte as (
    select
        pn,
        wk,
        prio,
        row_number() over (
            partition by pn
            order by (case when wk is not null then 0 else 1 end), wk, prio
        ) as rankid
     from #table
)
select pn,wk,prio
from cte
where rankid =1;
```